# Web browser capacity to display maximum records on Map using ArcGIS JSAPI 3.3/3.4

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have created ArcGIS JSAPI application in which I am displaying almost 50 thousand records at specific point.

As usual, my browser hangs (until 30 thousand its showing but after 30 thousand it hangs) while displaying such large records so I want to know the browser capacity to display number of records.

I am using ESRI 10.1 suit (ArcGIS Desktop and ArcGIS Server). I have changed default setting in ArcGIS Server to display records (default was 1000 and now its 80,000)

In addition, I am searching on Google regarding the browser capacity to display number of records on map but it is not clearly mention plus ESRI support people also cannot given such article for ArcGIS JSAPI and I have search in the web help also unable to find any document.

So is there any standard document or article that explains the maximum capacity to display number of records on map using ESRI JSAPI??

Tested on following Web browser: Firefox, Chrome, IE (very bad) and Safari (using latest version for all browsers)

Thanks in advance : )

Comment: 50K point? why would you do that? I remember there was a sample which showed that you could have reasonable performance only upto about 1K points. Let me try to find that out.

Comment: @Devdatta Tengshe  Analyzing social networking trend at particular area

Comment: You really need to think if you really need a feature service for that. Maybe you could do with a heatmap, or do the analysis in some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the article on graphic limits in the api help and how to test http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/limits_for_graphics.html

As has been said before though, usually you want the dynamic or tiled map service to display a large number of features, and then put the paired feature service into selection mode for user interaction with the individual features.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will go though the link